# how to make an edittext in Android Studio not required to fill?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to make a Tip calculator in Android Studio(android basic in kotlin,layout,user input 1), but I added an option to add your own tip percentage I like to call "customTip". I want to make edittext "customTip" to be optional, this is the declaration "customTip"

```
val customTipstr = binding.CustomTip.text.toString()
val customTip = customTipstr.toDoubleOrNull()
```

and then the error occurred at:

```
val tipPrecentage = when (binding.tipquestions.checkedRadioButtonId){
        R.id.tip_20 -> 0.2
        R.id.tip_15 -> 0.15
        R.id.tip_10 -> 0.1
        else -> customTip / 100 <-this is the error
    }
```

I tried to read some stackoverflow and I know how to fix it, make an if statement like this:

```
if (customTip == null ){
        return
    }
```

but I don't want anything to happen if "customTip" is null except when the user chooses the option which I tried: `if (customTip == null && binding.tipCustom.isChecked )` but the previous error comes back again. The question is, how to make "customTip" not required to be filled in until the user selects an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is simple.

```
if custom_tip is not empty/selected:
    use_custom()
else:
    use_selection()
```

Depends on how you have it. You can also show the logs to see what could be happening.